# Numba dictionary: signature in JIT() decorator

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, jit, numba

My function takes a list of numpy arrays and a dictionary (or a list of dictionaries) as input arguments and returns a list of values. The list of numpy arrays is long, and arrays may be of different shape. Though I can pass numpy arrays separately, for housekeeping purposes I really would like to form a tuple of numpy arrays and pass them as such into my function.
Without dictionary (which is specially formed according to numba >=0.43) the whole setup works fine - see the script below. Because the structure of input  and output is of Tuple form, JIT requires signature - it cannot figure out the type of data structure without it. However no matter how I try to declare my dictionary 'd' into the JIT decorator, I cannot manage to get the script working.
Please help with ideas or a solution if one exists.

Many thanks

'''python:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba import types
from numba.typed import Dict

@njit(  'Tuple( (f8,f8) )(Tuple( (f8[:],f8[:]) ))'  )

def somefunction(lst_arr):
    arr1, arr2 = lst_arr

    summ = 0
    prod = 1
    for i in arr2:
        summ += i
    for j in arr1:
        prod *= j

    result = (summ,prod)
    return result

a = np.arange(5)+1.0
b = np.arange(5)+11.0
arg = (a,b)
print(a,b)

print(somefunction(arg))


# ~~ The Dict.empty() constructs a typed dictionary.
d = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=types.float64,)

d['k1'] = 1.5
d['k2'] = 0.5
```

'''

I expect to pass 'd'-dictionary into 'somefunction' and use it inside with dict keys...Form example as follows: `result = (summ * d['k1'], prod * d['k2'])`

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba import types
from numba.typed import Dict

@njit(  'Tuple( (f8,f8) )(Tuple( (f8[:],f8[:]) ), Dict)'  )

def somefunction(lst_arr, mydict):
    arr1, arr2 = lst_arr

    summ = 0
    prod = 1
    for i in arr2:
        summ += i
    for j in arr1:
        prod *= j

    result = (summ*mydict['k1'],prod*mydict['k2'])
    return result

# ~~ Input numpy arrays
a = np.arange(5)+1.0
b = np.arange(5)+11.0
arg = (a,b)

# ~~ Input dictionary for the function 
d = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=types.float64)

d['k1'] = 1.5
d['k2'] = 0.5


# ~~ Run function and print results
print(somefunction(arg, d))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the version `0.45.1`. You can simply pass the dictionary without having to declare the type in the dictionary:

```
d = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=types.float64[:],
)
d['k1'] = np.arange(5) + 1.0
d['k2'] = np.arange(5) + 11.0

# Numba will infer the type on it's own.
@njit
def somefunction2(d):
    prod = 1

    # I am assuming you want sum of second array and product of second
    result = (d['k2'].sum(), d['k1'].prod())

    return result

print(somefunction(d))
# Output : (65.0, 120.0)
```

For reference, you check [this example](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#id6) from the official documentation.

**Update**:
In your case you can simply let `jit` infer the types on it's own and it should work, the following code works for me:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from numba import types
from numba.typed import Dict
from numba.types import DictType

# Let jit infer the types on it's own
@njit
def somefunction(lst_arr, mydict):
    arr1, arr2 = lst_arr
    summ = 0
    prod = 1
    for i in arr2:
        summ += i
    for j in arr1:
        prod *= j

    result = (summ*mydict['k1'],prod*mydict['k2'])
    return result

# ~~ Input numpy arrays
a = np.arange(5)+1.0
b = np.arange(10)+11.0  #<--------------- This is of different shape 
arg = (a,b)

# ~~ Input dictionary for the function 
d = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=types.float64)

d['k1'] = 1.5
d['k2'] = 0.5


# This works now
print(somefunction(arg, d))
```

You can see the official documentation [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html#advanced-types):

> Unless necessary, it is recommended to let Numba infer argument types by using the signature-less variant of @jit.

I tried various methods, but this is the only one that worked for the problem you specified.

Comment: Thanks, Mohammed. In this scenario, however, i cannot pass a tuple of numpy arrays, and it is a required input for the function...

Comment: @YevgeniyKarpekin Can you please update the description with the exact input you are expecting ? I am not to understand how you want to pass the tuple of numpy arrays since based on the examples you have given in the question, I am able to reproduce the same output. :)

Comment: @YevgeniyKarpekin also why would you need to pass tuple of numpy arrays seperately now ? Do you want to pass the tuple as keys or values of the dictionary ?

Comment: Good point - I have appended the question with the desired form of the script (that does not work for me). The reason I want to pass a tuple of arrays, because in my real script I have 5 numpy arrays to pass, each of which can have a different shape (so I cannot use 2d-array instead for JIT to infer the structure) and also a tuple of single value parameters (about 8). Indeed, I can pass them separately, but being able to pass the as just two tuples (one for arrays and one for parameters) and one dictionary makes the script tidier... Mainly for this reason...

Comment: ...it works indeed. I am puzzled - I did try this option with my original script, and it did not work. I might have been missing something else there. Sorry for what appears to be trivial question, but you have helped me a lot. Thanks! I will dig into my original function now...